# Printing method into textfield

Tags: java, methods, javafx, integer, textfield

How do I print a method into a textfield in JavaFX, the methods output is a Integer?

I have this class, which makes a dice, and i want to print the number into a textfield.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Dice {

public Die Die1 = new Die(6);
public Die Die2 = new Die(6);


public int throwDice(){
    Die1.throwDie();
    Die2.throwDie();
    return(Die1.diceEyes+Die2.diceEyes);
}

public void isItaPair(){
    if(Die1.diceEyes==Die2.diceEyes)
        System.out.println("Its a pair, throw again.");
    throwDice();
}

class Die {

private final int diceSides;
public int diceEyes;
private Random randomEyes = new Random();

public Die(int diceSides){
    this.diceSides = diceSides;

}


public void throwDie(){
    diceEyes = randomEyes.nextInt(diceSides)+1;
}
}
}
```

This is my JavaFX controller class, i want to print the outcome of Die1.throwDice() into the textfield dice_field.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import moole15gop_1.Dice;
import moole15gop_1.Player;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {




@FXML
private TextField user1;
@FXML
private TextField user2;
@FXML
private TextArea game_text1;
@FXML
private TextArea game_text2;
@FXML
private Button start_btn1;
@FXML
private Button start_btn2;
@FXML
private Button game_btn;
@FXML
private Label game_label;
@FXML
private TextField dice_field;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}

@FXML
private void start_action1(ActionEvent event) {
    user1.setText(user1.getText());
    System.out.println(user1.getText());
    if(user1.getText().isEmpty()){
        game_label.setText("You need to enter a username for the first     player!");             
    }
    else
    {
    game_text1.setText("Your username is " + user1.getText() + " and you have " + Player.playerMoney + ". You start at position " + Player.position);
    }

}

@FXML
private void start_action2(ActionEvent event) {
    user2.setText(user2.getText());
    System.out.println(user2.getText());
    if(user2.getText().isEmpty()){
        game_label.setText("You need to enter a username for the second player!");             
    }
    else
    {
    game_text2.setText("Your username is " + user2.getText() + " and you have " + Player.playerMoney + ". You start at position " + Player.position);
    }
}

Dice die1 = new Dice();

@FXML
private void game_action(ActionEvent event) {

}


}
```

The method should be printed when the game_action event is activated.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the `int` returned from the method to a `string` then print it to the text field.

Using

```
dice_field.setText(Integer.toString(new Dice().throwDice()));
```

OR

```
dice_field.setText(String.valueOf(new Dice().throwDice()));
```